# Magento add a form to a custom tab

Tags: php, magento

I have the following within my layout file:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>bulkupload</name>
            <block>bulkorderupload/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_bulkupload</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

I also have the corresponding Bulkupload.php file which extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template`

The tab shows up correctly; however, I am not sure how to add a form into the tab.  Any information on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow these steps for the custom tab.if there is still any issue you can ask question regarding that.check the [link](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/)